# Why does INSERT INTO including a blob not persist the record

Tags: java, mysql

I am writing automated tests using Java and Serenity and need the database to include a file. I have not been successful.

The tests will run on localhost on Windows, Mac and possibly Linux so absolute filenames will not work. I could not get INSERT INTO LOAD_FILE to work; I do not know where it's current folder is.

I have tried direct coding to the database. The files are from the project folder for convenience. (This is different from the program access, which uses Spring/Hibernate HQL) I do not get errors but the records do not show up in my test pages or in MySQL Workbench.

The MySQL code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS other_resources (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    orgid INTEGER NOT NULL,
    res_name VARCHAR(255),
    res_blob LONGBLOB NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_other_resources_orgid FOREIGN KEY (orgid) REFERENCES orgs (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I have tried three different combinations of code. All of the are successful. I am unsure of whether I have to copy the file or whether a Statement method will do it.

```
int orgId = rsOrg.getInt(1);
Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(".");

File file = new File(path.toString(), "pom.xml");
finStream = new FileInputStream(file);
byte[] fecho = new byte[(int) file.length()];
prepstatem = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO other_resources (orgid, res_name, res_blob) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
prepstatem.setInt(1, orgId);
prepstatem.setNString(2, "AnotherRes");
prepstatem.setBinaryStream(3, finStream, file.length());
int b = prepstatem.executeUpdate();
finStream.read(fecho);
finStream.close();

File fileT = new File(path.toString(), "serenity.properties");
FileInputStream finST = new FileInputStream(fileT);
PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO other_resources (orgid, res_name, res_blob) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
pst.setInt(1, orgId);
pst.setNString(2, "SerpropRes");
pst.setBlob(3, finST);
int c = pst.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("INSERT INTO tom " + c);
finST.close();

File fileD = new File(path.toString(), "database.properties");
FileInputStream finsDB = new FileInputStream(fileD);
byte[] dbecho = new byte[(int) fileD.length()];
Blob blobDB = new SerialBlob(dbecho);
PreparedStatement prest = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO other_resources (orgid, res_name, res_blob) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
prest.setInt(1, orgId);
prest.setNString(2, "DatabaseRes");
prest.setBlob(3, blobDB);
int d = prest.executeUpdate();
System.out.println("INSERT INTO tom " + d);
finsDB.close();
```

I queried the database to see whether the records had been added. The id, res_name and res_blob size were reported for all three files. However, my running application did not show the records and MySQL Workbench did not show the records.

```
Statement stOR = connection.createStatement();
String queryOR = "SELECT * FROM other_resources";
ResultSet rsOR = stOR.executeQuery(queryOR);
while (rsOR.next())
{
    System.out.println("id " + rsOR.getInt(1));
    System.out.println("orgid " + rsOR.getInt(2));
    System.out.println("name " + rsOR.getString(3));
    System.out.println("blob length " + rsOR.getBlob(4).length());
}
```

When I used a script in MySQL Workbench to add a record it showed an id of 4, as I would expect if these 3 files were added.

Is there something I missed or something quirky about MySQL?

Comment: I got it to work when I added `connection.commit();`

Answer (score 1):

I got it to work when I added `connection.commit();`